# Getting An IP Address in a CSLA remote data portal

Tags: networking, logging, csla

I'm writing an app in CSLA and want to log IP addresses, but only if the client is calling a remote data portal (such as the WCF one).

How can I get the client's IP address when executing within a remote data portal? I realize I could probably pass it with the request, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CSLA .NET forum thread on this topic](http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/t/9991.aspx)